# laravel validating if passed params are not equal

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating an application that lets a user create blogposts in multiple language. Per language the have a tab that contains the different fields. They can define the title, content and the slug. When they save the blogpost, all the params are validated through a FormRequest class as following:

```
{  
   "_method":"PUT",
   "_token":"eEDkVUU0cEcfAe3EQCiUIEdvCjTBqLFPT8CwW22D",
   "translations":{  
      "nl":{  
         "title":"A animi non est id repellat.nl",
         "slug":"veritatis-quos-iusto-eumnl",
         "content":"<p>ad-voluptate-sed-istenl<\/p>"
      },
      "en":{  
         "title":"Velit dignissimos suscipit unde et quod.en",
         "slug":"cupiditate-in-quaerat-uten",
         "content":"<p>rem-corporis-aut-aten<\/p>"
      },
      "fr":{  
         "title":"Mollitia reiciendis hic accusamus id dignissimos.fr",
         "slug":"voluptatem-iusto-quasi-rationefr",
         "content":"<p>accusantium-tempore-eos-nisifr<\/p>"
      },
      "de":{  
         "title":"Esse quasi ut delectus molestiae rem.de",
         "slug":"voluptates-excepturi-labore-mollitiade",
         "content":"<p>earum-delectus-velit-distinctiode<\/p>"
      }
   }
}
```

Now i would like the slug to be unique but the normal unique rule doesnt work since the passed params arent added to the database yet. What would be the best way to validate the slugs, so the are all unique?

Comment: why don't you auto generate slug based on post title ?

Comment: Would be better to let him choose the `slug` once. Then you just create it for the other languages too like `slug-fr`, `slug-de` etc . That way it's going to be always unique if the first `slug` is unique

Comment: It's not a good idea to pester the user by forcing him/her to modify the slugs until all of them are unique. It's much butter if your code modifies the non-unique slugs on the server. For example by adding a counter or language suffix.

Comment: In a controller, maybe try something like iterating through the translations, and ``$slug_exists = DB::table('pages')->select('*')->where('slug', $translation_slug)->count() > 0;``?

Comment: Make `slug` column unique and don't force user to make them unique make a code like every slug will be unique, you may add language name at the end of slug like 'abc_example_slug_eng', 'abc_exemple_limace_fr' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely must let them create custom slugs for each, you could try using the [*different* validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-different).

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'slug_field_1' => 'different:slug_field_2|different:slug_field_3|...',
    'slug_field_2' => 'different:slug_field_1|different:slug_field_3|...','
    ...
]);
```